# Problems on retrieving data from sqlite3 in C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm developing a program and this is part of my project: in this code I need to receive `filename` and `tweet` from the sqlite3 DB file and store it into the extended properties of a file. So this is the code:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell;
using System;
using System.IO;    
using System.Data.SQLite;

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var sqName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath("~valid path~"));
        SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection;
        m_dbConnection =
        new SQLiteConnection("Data Source="+ sqName + ";Version=3;");
        m_dbConnection.Open();
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM TweetText";
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
        SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();
        ShellFile.FromFilePath(reader["Filename"]).Properties.System.Comment.Value = reader["Tweet"];
    }
}
```

When I try to build this, VS 2017 says that I have error on `ShellFile.FromFilePath(reader["Filename"]).Properties.System.Comment.Value = reader["Tweet"]` and the error code is:

**CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'.**

But the fun thing is that if I replace the line with error like the following, it works:

```
Console.Write(reader["Filename"]);
Console.Write(reader["Tweet"]);
```

So my question is, why does C# recognizes `reader["Filename"]` as an object in the first code meanwhile it recognizes `reader["Filename"]` as string in the second code? How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Console.Write](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.console.write(v=vs.110).aspx) has multiple overloads. One of them admits object as parameter. Internally, Console.Write would call to the ToString() method of the object returned by reader["fieldname"].
reader["fieldname"] is resturning the underling database type. The c# compiler is complaing about the cast between 'object' to 'string'.

You can change

```
ShellFile.FromFilePath(reader["Filename"]).Properties.System.Comment.Value = reader["Tweet"];
```

by

```
ShellFile.FromFilePath(reader["Filename"].ToString()).Properties.System.Comment.Value = reader["Tweet"].ToString();
```

Comment: Oh I didn't know Console.Write has multiple overloads. Thanks so much!! It worked perfectly.

Comment: If you find this answer useful, don't forget to upvote with the up arrow!